# Installation of LinqToExcel nuget package making code to throw exception regarding log4net assembly

Tags: c#

I installed nuget Package LinqToExcel_64, which in turn added two refrences i.e.
1. LinqToExcel 1.7.1
2. log4net 1.2.11.0

I have already been using log4net(1.2.12.0) in my application.

My Code throws exception at below line of code:-

```
var dependants = from dependant in excel.Worksheet<ExcelDependant>()
                 select dependant;
```

Exception:-

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.11.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please Suggest how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were already using the newer version of dil and package has the dependency on older version. That's why this exception is occurring.  To resolve this, you can try to change the version of dependency dll in a configuration file located at:

Packages/"installed package name"/

Comment: Can you please tell how can I change the version of dll in packages folder?

Comment: When you install any package, all files are stored in a folder as packages/package_name. Here,  package_name will be something like  linqtosql. In that folder you will see some config files, there you can change the dependency to a particular version.